# ERROR - Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:untypedAtomic

Tags: xquery

Question: Find the total number of books published by each publisher. List a publisher and the total number of books published. Enclose the result of publisher with `publisher` element and the total number of books with `count` element. (Hint: read more on distinct-values)

XML Code:

```
<catalog>
    <book id="bk103">
      <author>
        <first>Corets</first>
        <last>Eva</last>
      </author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price currency="AU$">5.95</price>
      <publisher>Apress</publisher>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
      <keywords/>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>
        <last>Corets</last>
        <first>Eva</first>
      </author>
      <title>Oberons Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price currency="AU$">6.95</price>
      <publisher>Apress</publisher>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
      <keywords>
        <keyword>post-apocalypse</keyword>
      </keywords>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>
        <last>Corets</last>
        <first>Eva</first>
      </author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>15.95</price>
      <publisher>Morgan Kaufman</publisher>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberons Legacy.</description>
      <keywords/>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

My Answer:

```
for $b in distinct-values(//book/publisher)
let $c := count(//book[publisher = $b])
return 
<publish>
<publisher>{$b/publisher}</publisher>
<count>$c</count>
</publish>
```

The error I'm getting:
`ERROR - Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:untypedAtomic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for $b in distinct-values(//book/publisher)` binds the variable `b` to each item in the sequence of strings that `distinct-values` returns so to output that string simply use `<publisher>{$b}</publisher>`. You don't have any node there to use a path with a `/`.

You might want to use grouping instead

```
for $b in catalog/book
group by $pub := $b/publisher
return 
    <publish>
      <publisher>{$pub}</publisher>
      <count>{count($b)}</count>
    </publish>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8b

if you are not restricted to an XQuery version or dialect where that is not supported.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm only on XQuery 1.0, so it doesn't support 'group by' yet

Comment: But the first suggestion to use `<publisher>{$b}</publisher>` should solve the problem with the error: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8b/1

Answer (score 1):

Grouping will usually be more efficient:

```
for $book-group in //book
group by $publisher := $book-group/publisher
return <publish>
  <publisher>{ $publisher}</publisher>
  <count>{ count($book-group) }</count>
</publish>
```

Please note that the `fn:distinct-values` function will convert nodes to atomic values. This means that you will use the relationship to the original node.

Comment: I'm currently using XQuery 1.0, so it doesn't support the 'group by' function